# where to get Apache Tika jar?

Tags: apache-tika

All:

I try to build app using Apache Tika to parse PDF, but I wonder where can I get those libraries like tika-core/target/tika-core-*.jar and tika-parsers/target/tika-parsers-*.jar

I only find tika-app but there is no such jar like above.

http://tika.apache.org/1.11/gettingstarted.html

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachetikaparsersjar.htm try this

Comment: @VishwasJain Thanks, but failed to open that link!! ToT

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7lNx-oVlW1wWjZGZnpCcU9qeWc&usp=sharing try this then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache Tika has a large number of dependencies it needs to run. Without those present, it will do very little!

You therefore need do use a dependency management tool to not only get Apache Tika, but also the other libraries it needs. If you're using Apache Maven to do that, you can [follow the instructions on the Tika website to add it as a dependency to your project](http://tika.apache.org/1.11/gettingstarted.html#Using_Tika_as_a_Maven_dependency) with a section in your pom like:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
   <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
   <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

The [Apache Tika quickstart page](http://tika.apache.org/1.11/gettingstarted.html) also lists instructions on adding a dependency to Tika, along with all required dependencies, for both Gradle and Ivy builds too. You really ought to be using one of Maven, Gradle or Ivy to be handling the dependencies for you

If you really do want to handle all the dependencies yourself, you can find the Tika Core and Tika Parsers binary jars on Maven central, in the usual place. For Tika 1.11, that's [here for the tika-core jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-core/1.11/tika-core-1.11.jar) and [here for the tika-parsers jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-parsers/1.11/tika-parsers-1.11.jar). But, as previously mentioned, you almost certainly don't want to be doing that by hand!