# Need small apache.org.tika libraries (not the whole huge thing--tika.app.1.21.jar) to fix execution speed

Tags: java, netbeans-8, apache-tika

I have an old Netbeans program that I compiled long ago. It works okay. I want it to work better. One facet of the program is that it has code (that used) to find a string within files that "feel like text" files (*.doc*, *.txt, *.pdf, maybe more). In modifying the code some months or years ago, I "broke" the following `import` statements, which in turn broke code that references the imports:

```
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypeException;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
```

The error was "Package `org.apache.tika._______` does not exist."

The imports are used to make the code below find files containing, for example, the word "crud":

```
public static boolean objectFilecontainsObjectString(File file, String s)
  throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException,IOException,
         MimeTypeException,SAXException, TikaException
      {
        InputStream         stream    = new FileInputStream(file);
        AutoDetectParser    parser    = new AutoDetectParser();
        BodyContentHandler  handler   = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
        Metadata            metadata  = new Metadata();
        try
        {
          parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);
          return handler.toString().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          txaErrorsAppend("`contains() error for <" + file + ">: " + e + "\n");
          return false;
        }
        finally{  stream.close();  }
      }
```

(Lots of life's many complications kept me from following through way back when I was somewhat distractedly modifying and inadvertently breaking working code at the worst possible time.)

I think all I need to do is to add a `Library` (or two or so) that contain not much more than the `tika` routines that I'm trying to import **and so won't be many MB in size**.

Here's what I've tried. There are no longer any errors but it's slooooooooow.

I went to `http://www.apache.org/dist/tika/` and found a bunch of `1.21` files, no doubt the latest. But all the `.jar` files are from 47MB up to 73MB. My compiled `.jar` file is small enough but library file can be either 73MB or 47MB. Something is significantly slowing down execution. I assume size of library. (If I do NOT search for a string, execution is fine. Getting `objectFilecontainsObjectString` into the mix kills execution speed.)

Way back when, I vaguely recall finding multiple small libraries (`.jars`) that minimized my compiled library file size. But where are they today?

Any help to guide me to one or more "small" tika libraries or `.jar` files that will make my eventual `.jar` file be way under 1MB and produce a library file way smaller than 47 MB will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `objectFilecontainsObjectString` just doesn't take a long time to execute? And that it's not related to the size of the library?

Comment: Ah. Yes. *IF* the file being queried is huge and *IF* the routine doesn't return from querying until the *entire* file has been searched, that could take a very long time. Since posting my Question, I've modified the input parameters to exclude files larger than 10MB. It now runs faster. So, actually, this may be the only solution. I still want to see if I can find the libraries mentioned in my EDIT and see if there's any appreciable difference in speed. (I got the source code, hoping without hope, that making my own Netbeans project would be easy enough, but no. I'm not up for that just now.)

Comment: [1] You can probably find the **tika** jar files you want on Maven's web site (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/), but whether the approach you describe is a good idea is another matter. [2] You may want to look at the final paragraph of the accepted answer to the question [where to get Apache Tika jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33700221/2985643). [3] Is it a big deal to convert your project to use Maven?

Comment: @skomisa--[3] I have never willingly worked with or tried to learn Maven (I know collectively more about Gradle) but have lived with and either worked around (by patching the Maven problem as needed by Googling) the problem or asking for help. You seem to imply that it shouldn't be a big deal, but think about starting from scratch: *Is* it *then* sort of a big deal? (That's not supposed to be a snarky question: I'm asking you for your valued opinion under the condition of my total ignorance of Maven.) (I'm now following the two links...)

Comment: @skomisa--Malwarebytes blocked the link in [1] "because it may contain a Trojan.
We strongly recommend you do not continue" so I didn't and probably won't. However I, too, do wonder if my approach is a good idea.  [2] I was able to get the parsers jar file and will see how it goes after I fix the current new problem that involves `reflection`, used in order to see if fields exist in an object.